# Bitmask operations on slices of Python bytearrays

Tags: python, arrays, bitmask

Say I have a bytearray like the following :
`mask = bytearray([0b0001, 0b0100, 0b0111])`,
where each bit represents a certain flag. I would like to add a flag to slices of the mask array like so :
`mask[0:2] = mask[0:2] | 0b1000`
but I get a TypeError :
 `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'bytearray' and 'int'` 
what would be the most elegant way of doing this?

Tried this, as well :
`masks[0:2] = bytearray([bin(m | 0b0001) for m in masks[0:2]])`
with error :
`string must be of size 1`

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done directly without resorting to `numpy`, but you could work around it:

```
mask[:2] = (b | 0b1000 for b in mask[:2])

print(list(map(bin, mask)))
```

gets you:

```
['0b1001', '0b1100', '0b111']
```

You were close with your final attempt, but wrapping in `bin` was converting to a string representation, when you really wanted the original integer value.

Comment: Thanks -- I didn't even think about numpy. I can do something like :  `masks[0:2] = np.bitwise_or(masks[0:2], 0b0001)` and then see my changed flags with `map(np.binary_repr, masks)`